# Domain Forward in Plesk

Tags: dns, plesk

I have **mysite.eu** working fine, and I have registered a new site **mysite.co.uk** which I would like to forward to **mysite.eu**. According to various articles on the net, this is a pretty straightforward procedure yet, I can't make it to work since when i type **mysite.co.uk** I get a "This site can’t be reached www.***uppies.co.uk’s server DNS address could not be found". Here are my current settings:

[image]

and the .co.uk site hosting settings

[image]

Do i also have to edit the DNS settings maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the domain registar had not completed the .co.uk domain registration properly.

Answer (score 1):

Error massage you have see is about domain name and DNS, not about forwarding.

If you have recently register new domain, than DNS record of .co.uk site may be not propagated to all DNS servers and you have to wait about **24** hours.

Also check that you have `www` record of your new .co.uk domain:

Check for no-www record:
`nslookup <you domain name here>.co.uk`

Check for with-www record:
`nslookup www.<you domain name here>.co.uk`

If you need `www` part for domain you can add in your domain's registration panel.